# Feign Client: How to log the server name which the request was sent to?

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-netflix, netflix-feign, spring-cloud-feign

I am using a Feign Client to call a REST endpoint with success, and have logging turned on to FULL. This is helpfully shows me the request sent and the response received. However, I cannot see which server the request was sent to. It only shows me that it was POSTed to `http://foo-service` which is the name of the **service**, not the name of the **server**.

How can I log which **server name** this request was sent to?

This is what I see in the logs:

```
c.l.l.r.service.FooFeignClient : [FooFeignClient#bar] ---> POST http://foo-service/some-endoint HTTP/1.1
c.l.l.r.service.FooFeignClient : [FooFeignClient#bar] Accept: application/json
c.l.l.r.service.FooFeignClient : [FooFeignClient#bar] Content-Type: application/json
c.l.l.r.service.FooFeignClient : [FooFeignClient#bar] Content-Length: 15
c.l.l.r.service.FooFeignClient : [FooFeignClient#bar] 
c.l.l.r.service.FooFeignClient : [FooFeignClient#bar] {"name":"John"}
c.l.l.r.service.FooFeignClient : [FooFeignClient#bar] ---> END HTTP (15-byte body)
c.l.l.r.service.FooFeignClient : [FooFeignClient#bar] <--- HTTP/1.1 200 (8ms)
c.l.l.r.service.FooFeignClient : [FooFeignClient#bar] Transfer-Encoding: chunked
c.l.l.r.service.FooFeignClient : [FooFeignClient#bar] X-Application-Context: fooService:9006
c.l.l.r.service.FooFeignClient : [FooFeignClient#bar] Date: Tue, 10 Oct 2017 09:25:36 GMT
c.l.l.r.service.FooFeignClient : [FooFeignClient#bar] Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
c.l.l.r.service.FooFeignClient : [FooFeignClient#bar] 
c.l.l.r.service.FooFeignClient : [FooFeignClient#bar] {"result":"Hello John"}
c.l.l.r.service.FooFeignClient : [FooFeignClient#bar] <--- END HTTP (23-byte body)
```

To turn on logging, I declare this bean:

```
@Bean
public feign.Logger.Level feignLoggerLevel() {
    return Logger.Level.FULL;
}
```

We are using spring-cloud-netflix-core:1.1.0.M4

Answer (score 2):

You will need to provide your own `Logger` to achieve this.  The default `Logger` is very simple and logs the host before the request is sent.  When using `Ribbon` the information will be available with the `Response`.  If you override the `logAndRebufferResponse` method, the `response.url` property will be the entire url submitted, including host name.

```java
protected Response logAndRebufferResponse(
    String configKey, 
    Level logLevel, 
    Response response,
    long elapsedTime) throws IOException {

    /* ask the response for the request and log the uri */
    log(response.request.url());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Enable logging via logback and set log level of debug or these classes

```
<logger name="com.netflix.loadbalancer.BaseLoadBalancer" level="DEBUG"/>
<logger name="com.netflix.loadbalancer.LoadBalancerContext" level="DEBUG"/>
<logger name="com.netflix.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerCommand" level="DEBUG"/>
```

I can see where each request is going (server:port) and request failed on which server

```
DEBUG [          c.a.m.c.f.CommonProducerClient][72] - [CommonProducerClient#findAllEmployee] ---> GET http://COMMON-PRODUCER/allemployee HTTP/1.1
DEBUG [    c.n.loadbalancer.LoadBalancerContext][492] - COMMON-PRODUCER using LB returned Server: localhost:7001 for request http:///allemployee
DEBUG [      c.n.l.reactive.LoadBalancerCommand][314] - Got error java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect when executed on server localhost:7001
DEBUG [      c.n.l.reactive.LoadBalancerCommand][314] - Got error java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect when executed on server localhost:7001
DEBUG [      c.n.l.reactive.LoadBalancerCommand][314] - Got error java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect when executed on server localhost:7001
DEBUG [    c.n.loadbalancer.LoadBalancerContext][492] - COMMON-PRODUCER using LB returned Server: localhost:7003 for request http:///allemployee
DEBUG [          c.a.m.c.f.CommonProducerClient][72] - [CommonProducerClient#findAllEmployee] <--- HTTP/1.1 200 (4010ms)
```

From Logs its clear, first request went to port 7001, connection refused there, second request goes to 7003, all good there.